# How to escape ampersand in message text?

Tags: abap

I created a message class which contains the following text

> No K&C Data available for &1

```
DATA ls_return TYPE bapiret2.
DATA lv_par1 TYPE sy-msgv1 .

lv_par1 = '123456' .

CALL FUNCTION 'BALW_BAPIRETURN_GET2'
EXPORTING
  type   = 'I'
  cl     = 'Z_MY_MESSAGE_CLASS'
  number = 021
  par1   = lv_par1
IMPORTING
  return = ls_return.


WRITE ls_return-message .
```

The output of the small example programm will be

> No K123456C Data available for 123456

but should be

> No K&C Data available for 123456

So how do I escape(?) or change the entry of my message class?

Comment: Side note: it's recommended to use [`MESSAGE`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapmessage.htm) instead of `BALW_BAPIRETURN_GET2`: `MESSAGE i021(z_my_message_class) WITH lv_par1 INTO ls_return-message.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need use it as couple like below:

```
No K&&C Data available for &1
```